# How to write files in a CSV by sentence number, sentence (split by '|')?

Tags: python, csv, file-io

So I am trying to read a list of files, extract file ID and the abstracts. Every sentence of the abstracts should be written into a CSV file with file ID, sentence number and sentence split by '|'.

Someone tell me to use tokenizer of NLTK. I have NLTK installed but have no idea how to get it work with my code. My Python is 3.2.2. Below is my code:

```
import re, os, sys
import csv
# Read into the list of files.
topdir = r'E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part1\Part1' # Topdir has to be an object rather than a string, which means that there is no paranthesis.
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(topdir):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.txt','.pdf')):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

# Create a list and fill in the list with the abstracts. Every abstract is a string in the list.
capturedabstracts = []
for filepath in matches[:10]:  # Testing with the first 10 files.
    with open (filepath,'rt') as mytext:
    mytext=mytext.read()

        # code to capture files
    matchFile=re.findall(r'File\s+\:\s+(\w\d{7})',mytext)[0]
    capturedfiles.append(matchFile)


    # code to capture abstracts
    matchAbs=re.findall(r'Abstract\s+\:\s+(\w.+)'+'\n',mytext)[0]
    capturedabstracts.append(matchAbs)
    print (capturedabstracts)

with open('Abstract.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
for data in capturedabstracts:
    writer.writerow([data])
```

I am a beginner of Python, I might not be able to understand you comments, it would be great if you can provide comments with revised code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `writerow`

Try something like this:

```
with open('Abstract.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for data in capturedabstracts:
        writer.writerow([data])
```

Comment: "... Should be written into a CSV file with file ID, sentence number and sentence **split by '|'**."?

Answer (score 1):

As a first stab, look into [a sentence tokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html) and split the text into a list, then use writerows to store to csv:

```
with file(u'Abstract.csv','w') as outfile:
    sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    list_of_sentences = sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip())
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, headers = ['phrase'], delimiter = '|',  quotechar = None, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar="\\")
    for phrase in list_of_sentences:
        phrasedict = {'phrase':phrase}
        writer.writerow(phrase)
    writer.close()
```